# How can I avoid mixing up pins or mirroring pinouts on pin header connectors?

Tags: pcb-design, pinout, header

A chronic problem for me when laying out PCBs is pinout mixups on header connectors -- sometimes I will inadvertently interchange adjacent pins or hook pins to things that seem right but aren't, at others I will mirror or rotate the connector altogether from its expected mating orientation.  While debugging tools with flylead cables (my FTDI cable and Bus Pirate both have this) or female-terminated jumper wires can be quite helpful when working around this when prototyping, they're quite a chore to use compared to the correct mating connector, and not always possible now that some things (ARM Cortex-M JTAG/SWD, most notably) are migrating to 50mil header pitch from 100mil.  Building one-off adapters is also a hassle, and the extra mounting height an adapter imposes is sometimes undesirable from a mechanical standpoint as well.

**How can I prevent these problems at the design stage -- especially rotated/mirrored pinouts, as they seem to be a bigger problem for me than swapped pins?**  Also, are there design strategies I can use to reduce the impact of this class of problems in terms of rework/adaptation effort needed?  I am doing schematic capture here -- I've had this problem when working both with gEDA in the past and currently with KiCAD.  DRC and netlisting aren't able to catch these issues because I'm dealing with *generic pins* on the header side, and sometimes on the "other end" (i.e. the component the connector is wired to) as well -- and these problems are occurring *in schematic capture* -- not necessarily at actual layout time.

Comment: Please let us know if you are laying out by hand or are using a schematic capture program and pcb layout program.  If the latter, the programs should catch the mistakes.  Which, I think, leaves (most) of us confused.

Comment: Would using polarized connectors solve the problem?  They can be plugged in only one way.

Comment: @NickAlexeev -- sadly, no -- this is a layout-stage mixup problem, not a "plugging things in backwards like a derp" problem :/

Answer (score 7):

If you are not already doing so you should make sure to use a schematic capture tool that can then create a net list of the design connections. This can then be fed into the PCB layout tool to specify all the connections. This goes a long way to eliminating issues because:

1. It is far easier to get the connections down right on the schematic. In particular things are pictoral and much easier to check.
2. Working in schematic you can deal with connectors based entirely on the pin numbers. It can help to create schematic symbols that have a connection layout that logically maps to the physical connector. This helps with envisioning what hooks next to what.
3. Working in the pcb layout package concentrates at the start of creating footprints for all your parts, especially connectors, where you take great care to match the part drawing of the datasheet and assign the pin numbers properly. Also make sure the footprint includes markers or special features that indicate pin one position. DO not fall into the trap of using ready made library symbols that may have somebody elses ideas on how the pins are numbered.
4. It is extremely valuable to have in hand physical part samples, especially all the connectors and their mating parts. These help to visualize the orientations and pin configurations. They also offer a way to measure dimensions that may translate to silk screen outlines but are not specified in the data sheet.
5. Done properly these steps should almost 100% eliminate having to define net hook up assignments in the layout tool.....which as you have seen can be error prone.

Comment: One problem though -- I *am* defining net assigments at schematic time and it *still* doesn't stop me from fubar'ing pinouts!

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Are you running a design checker after you lay the PCB out? That should tell you that you've made a mistake if you've messed things up.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel & @ tangrs - If the schematic is correct and a design checker says OK then it is a direct consequence of the points 3) and 4) that I made above. Get the connector footprint right and the rest falls into place. If you fall into the trap of not caring about what generic connector footprints that you put on your PCB layout then you end up with the problems similar to what you experience. You gotta step up and pay attention to initial details and the rest is easy and can be foolproof. Take a shortcut and you take what you get.

Comment: Should I be creating custom schematic symbols for the connectors as well? It sounds like that doing 3) while using a generic symbol at the capture stage actually risks a mistake that I recall making before -- i.e. using a schematic symbol and a footprint that have different ideas about how pins should be numbered!

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Yes, I recommend building your own libraries. There are multiple reasons for this, and they include accuracy and consistency. Also, if your software is letting you route to the wrong pins even when your schematic is correct, and not giving you errors, then you need a different software package

Comment: Re: custom symbols. YES DEFINITELY. If the libraries you have don't match both the footprint and the manufacturer pin numbering, sit down and make a fully-consistent set of components.

Comment: I build all my own libraries. The schematic symbols get created in parallel with the layout footprints. This is the only way to be fully in control of your destiny. (Note that if you work at a big company that maintains a company wide library with dedicated librarians that maintain it plus a rigorous design review process with checkoffs on each library item from mechanical eng, design eng, mfg/test eng and cad layout folks then this would not be necessary. At same time you would not be permitted to use non library parts unless you submitted them for implementation to the librarian.

Answer (score 3):

You need to introduce a review process before you take your board to manufacturing. If you have co-workers or co-conspirators, get them to sit down and ask mean questions about your design.

Before it gets to that though, you should be doing an audit of EVERY pin on EVERY part. "Does this go where it should?" "Should it be going somewhere it's not?" "Are these signal levels compatible?" "Is this part rating adequate?"

Make sure every connector has the right pinout at this step. Is the footprint validated so that the pin numbers match the physical component? If not, double check that.

This seems like a huge time waster, and it is, right until you find a critical error before you get boards made. You'll probably end up finding something big in every board you review, at least until you get a good set of validated design snippets in your inventory.

Comment: If only the pin numbers were like....stamped into the connector ;P (Many connector datasheets aren't very clear about which pin is which, IME, either).

Comment: If you can't tell which pin is which in the datasheet, that's a different issue altogether, but I'm confident that if you put in a concerted effort you can sort it out.

Comment: This is really what I'm trying to tell you that it comes down to.. getting mad at yourself enough times for not checking things well enough that you make it a habit to go through everything with a fine-tooth comb before it goes out. There's no trick for that.

Comment: The amazing thing is how hard the PCB CAD package vendors will try to emphasize how many components that they have in their standard library. I've found that it often actually takes longer to do the fine tooth comb treatment of standard library components than it does to create from scratch. This is especially true if you do not need to create a plethora of specialty layer defines for each footprint.

Comment: I've found the Altium Vault parts to be pretty good in a pinch, but most of my components are custom made.